# How to start/uninstall eddie-vim?

Tags: vim

I installed `eddie-vim` for my MacOS after exploring several vim options. Quite weiredly there's no GUI app in the /Applications folder.

I installed it with this command:

```
sh <(curl -L https://github.com/kaochenlong/eddie-vim/raw/master/utils/install.sh)
```

It is successfully installed. Now everytime I try to start vim it gives this output:

> MYHOST:.vim song$ vim
>   Error detected while processing /Users/song/.vimrc:
>   line   13:
>   E117: Unknown function: pathogen#infect
>   line   14:
>   E117: Unknown function: pathogen#helptags
>   Press ENTER or type command to continue

I have to press ENTER to proceed.

So I have 2 questions:

1. Does eddie-vim have a GUI?
2. If not, how to uninstall eddie-vim? I've tried changing install to uninstall/remove/uninst in the install command, which doesn't work.

Thanks. I'm kind of obsessive-compulsory-disorder. Knowing there's something in my computer which I would never use is torture....

Answer (score 1):

[`eddie-vim`](https://github.com/kaochenlong/eddie-vim/) is a set of configurations for vim and not a GUI application.
If you want a GUI, install Gvim or its alternatives.

What the installation script does is to backup current `.vim` and `.vimrc`, clone the repository and use it as vim configurations.

> ```
> # detect if there's a .vim folder
>   if [ -d $vim_folder ]
>   then
>     echo "\033[0;31mYou already have a .vim folder in your home directory.\033[0;m"
>     read -p "Would you like to backup your .vim folder first? [y/n] " ans
>     if [ "$ans" == "y" ]
>     then
>       echo "backup your original $vim_folder to $vim_folder-$(date +%Y%m%d)-$backup_rand"
>       mv $vim_folder $vim_folder-$(date +%Y%m%d)-$backup_rand
>     else
>       exit
>     fi
>   fi
>
> echo $vim_rc
>
> # check if vimrc is already exist
>   if [ -L $vim_rc ] || [ -f $vim_rc ]
>   then
>     echo "\033[0;31mThere's .vimrc in your home directory.\033[0;m"
>     read -p "Would you like to backup your .vimrc first? [y/n] " ans
>     if [ "$ans" == "y" ]
>     then
>       echo "backup your original $vim_rc to $vim_rc-$(date +%Y%m%d)-$backup_rand"
>       mv $vim_rc $vim_rc$(date +%Y%m%d)-$backup_rand
>     else
>       exit
>     fi
>   fi
> ```

Also set up symlinks to `.vimrc`

> ```
> case $ans in
>    1)
>      echo "using standard vimrc.."
>      ln -s $vim_folder/vimrc $vim_rc
>      ;;
> ```

In-order to uninstall (or undo the changes), You just need to replace `.vim` folder with `.vimXXXXXXXX` and `.vimrc` with `.vimrcXXXXXXXX` which were replaced on installation of `eddie-vim` (You can do this if you had chose to backup `.vim` and `.vimrc` when the scripts prompt you to)